# Progressbar behaves strangely

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, progress-bar

I just created an application in C# that uses a thread which polls the UART for a receive event.
If data is received an event is triggered in my main thread (GUI) and a progress bar is controlled via *PerformStep()* method (of course, I previously set the *Max* value accordingly).
*PerformStep* is invoked using the following expression to handle cross threading

```
this.Invoke((Action)delegate{progressBar2.PerformStep();})
```

When running this application the progressbar never hits its final value. It stops at 80%. When debugging and stopping at the line mentioned above, everything works fine using single steps. I have no idea what is going one!

Start read thread on main thread:

```
pThreadWrite = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadThread));
pThreadWrite.Start();
```

Read Thread:

```
private void ReadThread()
{
while(1)
{
    if (ReceiveEvent)
    {       
    FlashProgressBar();
    }
}
}
```

Event that is triggered in main thread:

```
private void FlashProgressBar()
{
this.Invoke((Action)delegate { progressBar2.PerformStep();});
}
```

(It's a simplified representation of my code)

It seems as if the internal progress is faster than the visual one.

**EDIT 2:**
OK, I think I git it. The problem is the *invoke* method to handle cross threading. I found this quote on SO:

*No, it's fundamental to any UI at least as far as Windows goes. The message architecture in Windows Forms is nothing new, it's the same way even a C++ application works in Windows. If you're trying to update a progress bar or something you shouldn't be invoking across threads. Instead use interlocked writes to a progress variable which the UI thread reads at certain intervals.*

and

*Yes, there can be an arbitrarily long delay. Invoke works by sending a Windows message to the target control, so it will only get processed when the target thread pumps messages. If the thread is already processing a message, and that processing takes time, then there may be an appreciable delay before the thread pumps its next message and thereby processes the Invoke.*

so I need to find another solution like waiting the *BeginInvoke* method to be finished!

**EDIT:**

if I insert some thread.sleep() statements it seems to work. may be there is a problem with a timer used. This timer is started by the read thread and if it exceeds the event is triggered:

Read thread:

```
 private void ReadThread()
    {
        FTDI.FT_STATUS ftStatus = FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK;
        UInt32 numBytesAvailable = 0;         

        while (true)
        {
            ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.GetRxBytesAvailable(ref numBytesAvailable);
            if (ftStatus == FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                 // read data and start timer                    
                 TimeoutWaitForAckn.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, if the timer exceeds the event is triggered. the sleep statement nails it:

```
    private void Timeout_Handler(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        Trigger_ReportBufferReceivedEvent(ReceiveBuffer);
    }
```

Are there any known issues considering threads, timers and event? the System.Timers.Timer is used.

Comment: WinForms or WPF or SilverLight or what?

Comment: (If WinForms) Have you taken account of the fact that `PerformStep` advances by the amount given by the `Step` property of the `ProgressBar`, and that this property defaults to `10` rather than `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think we will be able to help you with a fragment of code that we cannot compile or run and without knowing the rest of your application.

I have tried to reproduce the problem you describe and I’m afraid it is not happening. I have [posted my code here in case you want to try it too](http://csharp.pastebin.com/YG5nJN27) (it is effectively the same as your code). The code shows a form with a progress bar and a button. You click the button, the progress bar goes all the way up to 100% within 10 seconds. Once it reaches the end, the `Debugger.Break()` triggers.

If you can change the above code into one that actually reproduces your problem, and you post that as a self-contained example, then we will be able to help you.

Comment: I think the code itself is too complex and too much to post it here, so I tried to extract the segments concerned. But if your example works fine there might be a problem with another part of the software...